# All 4 tyres for Santro Xing 145/70/ R17 can be used instead of original 155/70/R17 tyre size

Tags: tires, hyundai, safety, santro

I have new 4 tyre size of 145/70/R17,  can I use these tyres instead of 155/70/R17 original tyre size. I will replace all 4 tyres with new tyres. Is it recommended. Shall I face any technical problems for the same?
Pls recommend.

Comment: Will having non-standard size tires on your vehicle affect your insurance?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the tyres you have are R13 as this vehicle runs 13" diameter wheels as standard.

The first number (145 or 155) is the width of the tread part of the tyre in mm.  Going from 155 to 145 will cause no problems because the shoulders of the tyre will be just 5mm further inwards than they were previously.  This will mean that the tyres will not cause any rubbing.

The second number, the 70 is a percentage which shows how big the sidewalls are relative to the tread pattern.  So, on the 145 tyres the sidewall will be 7mm smaller than on the 155/70 tyres.  This may throw your speedometer clibration out very slightly (but not significantly).

The only other things you need to check is that your 145 tyres have a suitable load and speed rating for your vehicle.  After the first set of numbers (i.e. 155/70R13) there will be another set, typically something like 89W or 91T.  The number is the load rating (i.e. how much weight the tyre is able to support) and the letter is the speed rating.

Provided that the load and speed ratings are reasonable, I would personally have no hesitation in going from 155 to 145 tyres, all else being equal.